# creating insert sorted void function

Tags: c, recursion, tree, insert

Hi can someone explain to me what is the problem here! I'm trying to create a insert sorted function for my tree and I'm using void function! and I got this error:

a value of type `void` cannot be assigned to an entity of type `struct treeNode`

```
struct treeNode {
    int data;
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
};

typedef struct treeNode *BSTree;

void insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data) {
    if (!*tree) {
        tree = createNode(data);
    } else
    if (data < (*tree)->data) {
        (*tree)->left = insertSorted((*tree)->left, data); //it's show upp here
    } else
        (*tree)->right = insertSorted((*tree)->right, data);

    return tree;
}
```

Comment: `void insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data)` => `BSTree * insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data)`

Comment: Sidenote: **never ever** `typedef` pointers!

Comment: I have just asked him if he understands this typedef. I afraid he does not as he wants return type of this function to be int :)

Comment: i just said int as example for compiler not creating an error i do understand that it must be BSTree * insertSorted

Answer (score 4):

```
void insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data)
{

    if (!*tree)
    {
        tree = createNode(data);
    }
    else if (data < (*tree)->data)
    {
    (*tree)->left = insertSorted((*tree)->left, data); //it's show upp here
    }
    else
        (*tree)->right = insertSorted((*tree)->right, data);
    return tree;
}
```

should be

```
void insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data){
    if (!*tree)
        *tree = createNode(data);
    else if (data < (*tree)->data)
        insertSorted(&(*tree)->left, data);//1st argument require `BSTree *tree`
    else
        insertSorted(&(*tree)->right, data);
}
```

or

```
BSTree insertSorted(BSTree tree, int data)
{

    if (!tree)
    {
        tree = createNode(data);
    }
    else if (data < tree->data)
    {
        tree->left = insertSorted(tree->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        tree->right = insertSorted(tree->right, data);
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the function as having the return type void then any return statement shall not contain an expression and you shall not try to assign a void "value" to any object.

The function can look the following way

```
void insertSorted( BSTree *tree, int data )
{
    if ( *tree == NULL )
    {
        *tree = createNode( data );
    }
    else if ( data < ( *tree )->data )
    {
        insertSorted( &( *tree )->left, data );
    }
    else
    {
        insertSorted( &( *tree )->right, data );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct treeNode
{
    int data;
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
};

typedef struct treeNode* BSTree;

BSTree createNode( int data )
{
    BSTree node = malloc( sizeof( *node ) );

    if ( node )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}

void insertSorted( BSTree *tree, int data )
{
    if ( *tree == NULL )
    {
        *tree = createNode( data );
    }
    else if ( data < ( *tree )->data )
    {
        insertSorted( &( *tree )->left, data );
    }
    else
    {
        insertSorted( &( *tree )->right, data );
    }
}

void displayTree( BSTree * tree )
{
    if ( *tree != NULL )
    {
        displayTree( &( *tree )->left );

        printf( "%d ", ( *tree )->data );

        displayTree( &( *tree )->right );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    BSTree tree = NULL;
    int a[] = { 1, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        insertSorted( &tree, a[i] );
    }

    displayTree( &tree );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 3 4 5 7 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Void functions do not return a value. That is the problem. You need to remove the return or change the function declaration to return that pointer

Comment: Well i do understand that void does not return the value, but is there anyway to solve this i mean i can change the function from void to int but i still need to make it work through void

Comment: you need to change to the BSTree * insertSorted(..... BTW do you understand what BSTree type is?

Comment: Yes i do, im still wondering about the void and is there anyway to make it work??

Comment: <irony> Of course you can make it void **</irony> if you want to keep the word void in the definition.